# Is it possible in SQl Server to create a self-maintaing table with self-references

Tags: sql-server, azure

I'm using Azure's SQL Database & MS SQL Server Management Studio and I wondering if its possible to create a self-referencing table that maintains itself.

I have three tables: Race, Runner, Names. The Race table includes the following columns:

1. Race_ID (PK)
2. Race_Date
3. Race_Distance
4. Number_of_Runners

The second table is Runner.  Runner contains the following columns:

1. Runner_Id (PK)
2. Race_ID (Foreign Key)
3. Name_ID
4. Finish_Position
5. Prior_Race_ID

The Names Table includes the following columns:

1. Full Name
2. Name_ID

The column of interest is Prior_Race_ID in the Runner Table.  I'd like to automatically populate this field via a Trigger or Stored Procedure, but I'm not sure if its possible to do so and how to go about it. The goal would be to be able to get all a runners races very quickly and easily by traversing the Prior_Race_ID field.

Can anyone point me to a good resource or references that explains if and how this is achievable.   Also, if there is a preferred approach to achieving my objective please do share that.

Thanks for your input.

Comment: 1) I think the first table you describe is `Race`, not `Runner`, because otherwise you're telling us about the `Runner` table twice, and it has different columns. 2) Having to traverse `Prior_Race_ID`s to find each previous race would be horrific. SQL works best with *set* based queries, and you seem to be aleady set up for that by querying all entries in `Runner` with the *same* `Name_ID` value.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever so your vote would be not to try to add the prior race Id.  That being the case, if I want to include each runners prior race on a report for a particular race how would I achieve this efficiently.   Are you suggesting I should run a query for each runner.

Comment: Sounds like you need a recursive cte here.

Comment: You could do it with a computed column that calls a UDF.

Comment: @SeanLange thanks for the feedback.  How do you compare the cte solution to the computed column/UDF that Tab proposed

Comment: What you have is a many to many relationship between races and runners. You really need a redesign not try to work around this poor design. You should have a RaceRunner table with raceid and runnerid instead of having raceid and previous raceid in the runner table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so we want, for each Competitor (better name than `Names`?), to find their two most recent races. You'd write a query like this:

```
SELECT
    * --TODO - Specific columns
FROM
    (SELECT
         *, --TODO - Specific columns
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY n.Name_ID ORDER BY r.Race_Date DESC) rn
    FROM
       Names n
          inner join
       Runners rs
          on
             n.Name_ID = rs.Name_ID
          inner join
       Races r
          on
             rs.Race_ID = r.Race_ID
    ) t
WHERE
    t.rn in (1,2)
```

That should produce two rows per competitor. If needed, you can then PIVOT this data if you want a single row per competitor, but I'd usually leave that up to the presentation layer, rather than do it in SQL.

And so, no, I wouldn't even have a `Prior_Race_ID` column. As a general rule, don't store data that can be *calculated* - that just introduces opportunities for that data to be incorrect compared to the base data.

Answer (score 1):

run the following sql(The distinct here is to avoid that a runner has more than one race at a same day):

```
update runner r1
set r1.prior_race_id = 
(
select distinct race.race_id from runner, race where runner.race_id = race.race_id and runner.runner_id = r1.runner_id group by runner.runner_id having race.race_date = max(race.race_date)
)
```